# Xamarin.Essentials Preferences Generic Wrapper

Tags: c#, xamarin, generics, xamarin.forms, xamarin.essentials

I'm trying to make a wrapper of `Preference` class in `Xamarin.Essentials`

Preference class set function has following method signatures. So I wanted to use a generic wrapper on it.

`Preferences.Set(string key, string/int/bool/DateTime value) etc.`

I want something like this(*code below*).

`GetStorage` is working fine.

`SetStorage` is giving me **ERROR!!**

```
public StorageService: IStorageService
{
    public T GetStorage<T>(string key)
    {
        object value = Preferences.Get(key,null);
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
    }

    public void SetStorage<T>(string key, T value)
    {
        Preferences.Set(key, value); // ERROR HERE
    }
}
```

How do I get this working???

Comment: How will you have a generic setter for multiple overrides when your setter isn't generic. The only way to do this would be to have type-specific overrides. This might have worked if you had a setter that takes System.Objects But since that is not the case this cannot be Generic. Also shouldn't you be using Method Overriding here instead of Generics if you really want a solution

Comment: @FreakyAli I get why it won't work. That's why I posted it here. If there is some workaround to do that. It'll be healpful

Comment: FreakyAli is right. You'll need to override  each type, similar to how how [Xamarin does it](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/blob/main/Xamarin.Essentials/Preferences/Preferences.shared.cs). If you're just doing a simple wrapper with no custom logic, there are [existing nugets](https://github.com/rdavisau/essential-interfaces) that will generate the interfaces for you.

Comment: How are we supposed to know what “ERROR” means?

Comment: @ShubhamTyagi The problem is your question is something that is impossible to do in OOP, could work on javascript may be!

Comment: @Jason The highlighted line is incorrect syntax. Hence the question

Comment: What is the specific error message?